# Flutter: How to make GridView's row's height to wrap the content?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a Grid view with 2 columns, where each item can have different height as shown in the image. Is it possible to set the height of row equal to maximum item's height in that row, in other words, is it possible to make row wrap its content independent from its items height?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**You can't `GridView` wrap content** because all item ar scaled up to the largest item's heigth. You  can either change `childAspectRatio` (there will be empty space on smaller items) or user `StaggeredGridview` [From here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

> A Flutter staggered grid view which supports multiple columns with rows of varying sizes.

It is really easy to use

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  itemCount: 8,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: new Center(
        child: new CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: new Text('$index'),
        ),
      )),
  staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
      new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1),
  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
)
```

You can find more examples in [Example project](https://github.com/letsar/flutter_staggered_grid_view/tree/master/example).

Comment: Thanks, but the aspect ration will not solve the problem

Comment: `(there will be empty space on smaller items)` that means this is not the best solution. **YOU SHOULD use `StaggeredGridView` ***